# MySQL special ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Suppose I have the following table

```
name        | genre
---------------------
book 1      | scifi
book 2      | horror
book 3      | scifi
book 4      | romance
book 5      | horror
```

How can I sort the table above by "genre" in `SQL` to get the following results. Please note the order. It's H S R, and not H R S. Is it possible to achieve this without using `UNION`?

```
name        | genre
------------------------
book 2      | horror
book 5      | horror
book 1      | scifi
book 3      | scifi
book 4      | romance
```

**Edit:** There are only 3 genres.

Comment: What is that order?  Where would a book of the "fantasy" genre sit?

Comment: Valid point. There would be only and only 3 genres.

Comment: Only 3 genres forever and ever?

Comment: Could you explain the genre order?

Comment: I think adding a table for the "weight" of the genre would really help.  Then you could just inner join and order by genre weight.

Comment: Horror, Scifi, Romance. Forever ever.

Comment: Seriously?  No autobiographies?  If that's the case, then as a quick-n-dirty solution, could you just name your genres '0 horror', '1 scifi', and '2 romance'?  If you don't want it showing up in your user interface, just whack out the number in your client app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the field function to customise the sort order

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY FIELD(`genre`, 'horror', 'scifi', 'horror'), `name`;
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know this existed!

Comment: it's not ideal, since it's a hard coded solution, but it will work & it's quick

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`select * from table order by case when genre="romance" then 1 else 0 end, genre;`

Comment: Agreed; or perhaps just `... ORDER BY CASE genre WHEN 'horror' THEN 1 WHEN 'scifi' THEN 2 WHEN 'romance' THEN 3 END`.

Comment: The `FIELD()` function works in the same way by assigning the matched value the position index [field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: @BenRowe: Aye, I like your answer (and have +1'd it) - hadn't thought of using `FIELD` here.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the ENUM answer above, add a genre order table that contains something like:

```
genre_name | sort_order
-----------------------
scifi      | 2
horror     | 1
romance    | 3
```

Then run your query as:

```
SELECT name, genre
FROM books JOIN genres ON books.genre = genres.genre_name
ORDER BY genres.sort_order, books.name;
```

This has the added advantage of allowing you to quickly and easily add genres without changing hard-coded ENUMs in your code.  Either way should work, though.

Comment: If you are adding a sort_order column, it is probably better to create a separate table with genre and sort_order columns, to make it easier to change the order if you have to down the line.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting, a separate genre order table.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could define your genre column as an `ENUM` type.  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html):

   > `ENUM` values are sorted based on their index numbers, which depend on the order in which the enumeration members were listed in the column specification. For example, `'b'` sorts before `'a'` for `ENUM('b', 'a')`. The empty string sorts before nonempty strings, and NULL values sort before all other enumeration values.

   Therefore:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY genre ENUM('horror', 'scifi', 'romance');
   ```

   Your query would then be:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY genre ASC;
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could store a table of genres with their position in the ordering and join your query with that:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE genres (genre VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, position INT);
   INSERT INTO genres VALUES ('horror', 1), ('scifi', 2), ('romance', 3);
   ALTER TABLE my_table ADD FOREIGN KEY (genre) REFERENCES genres (genre);
   ```

   Your query would then be:

   ```
   SELECT   my_table.*
   FROM     my_table JOIN genres USING (genre)
   ORDER BY genres.position ASC;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the table is very inefficient (redundant data) - so just make a new table with all the genres in it, and use foreign keys.

Secondly, add a column to the genres table, and assign a unique number to each genre, according to the desired position in your sort - and then just sort the data by that column from now on, done (and sort order can easily be changed any time).

Comment: Making genre of type enum would be a lot more efficient, as it would eliminate the need for a join, and MySQL only stores enum values once per table.

Comment: @Jeshurun: went with the simplest solution, since the table wasn't even normalized, maybe enums are a bit of a stretch for him... and its easier to just update sort numbers or insert new genres, then to alter table every time